# What is the purpose of the hourglass item?

Tags: dragon-ball-z-dokkan-battle

So the hourglass is an item required to Reverse a transcended UR or higher character back to the pre-Dokkan Awakened status.

What use is this? Why would you want to reverse awaken a unit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because then only certain characters can level up your Super Attack (hereafter SA), if it is Dokkan Awakened. If you reverse the Dokkan Awakening, you can use more characters to level up a characters SA or unlock more nodes for their Hidden Potential, instead of trying to unlock one node by Dokkan Awakening the same character. It's quite useful, if you mess up once or twice.